# Finding reactants in a azo-coupling reaction whose product is given

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

> Find the reactants of the following azo-coupling reaction:
> [image]

My solution would look like this:

[image]

**My reason for the above answer**

The amino Group is more activating than the nitro group and therefore the diazonium salt had to be on the left ring.

Is this correct? If not, what is the correct explanation?

**Edit:** To get to the azo-coupling product shown above I should use a high temperature, or? So, the reaction has to be thermodynamically controlled because the azo-group is localized on the  carbon.

Comment: You have 2 amino groups in your starting material. Do you think there will be any problem of selectivity in the initial diazotisation?

Comment: If the diazonium salt would have been made on the naphthol molecule, this molecule would have had two amino groups. And the two amino groups would have produced two diazonium salts. This could not be used to obtain the wanted final diazo compound.

Comment: Well, no it's not good at all; in particular your rationale is completely backwards.

Comment: In the future, please use a 2D chemical sketcher like [ChemDoodle](https://web.chemdoodle.com/demos/2d-sketcher) or [ChemDraw online](https://chemdrawdirect.perkinelmer.cloud/js/sample/index.html) to draw structures: they're easier to use and produce better results

Answer (score 3):

The comments summarized the reasons well: the diazotization reaction for the initial structure would produce a mixture of $\alpha$-azo and $\beta$-azo compounds, which would give a mixture of products. Also, **diazonium salts couple with activated aromatic systems**. The diazonium salt shown would not couple with nitrobenzene, which is highly deactivating and does not favour electrophilic aromatic substitution.

Also, having an electron withdrawing group on the diazonium salt favours the reaction. Thus, the correct solution would have the azo group on the smaller, less activated benzene ring rather than the larger, more activated naphthalene ring.

Comment: But isn't $\alpha$-position on napthalene more "prone" to EAS than $\beta$?

Comment: @RobinSingh yes it is, and major product would be coupling opposite to phenol group. However, this looks more like a textbook problem of determining which ring would have the azo group initially, so I suggested the above. If you have to practically synthesize the first molecule, then there are a lot more reactions involved.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to summarize the comments at that point, and (or at least) link to them. There could be new comments later, or older ones deleted, it's better to have it all in one place.